# Running side containers in Google cloud run or Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

Is it possible to run side containers or init containers in Google Cloud Run or App Engine? I couldn't find any documentation of this and trying to ask this on GCP support forums I was directed to ask at stack-overflow. If possible how would you accomplish this? I came across this [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sidecars-docker) but it wasn't helpful.

I know it is possible with GKS but trying to do the same with these services.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what would be a "side" container in the context of Cloud Run?  For Cloud Run, we have the notion of a container that scales down to zero instances.  When REST requests arrive, instances will spin up and you will be billed only for in-flight work.

Comment: The short answer is no. Anything you want to do in your container you must do yourself. The exception is Cloud SQL Proxy which is sidecar'd to your container.

Comment: Thanks figured as much @John.....@Kolban my question was answered per above

Answer (score 9):

You can't, for now, running a Pod on Cloud Run, you can only run a container. However, it's possible to run a multi process container for helping you to achieve this.

You can find [here](https://ahmet.im/blog/minimal-init-process-for-containers/) and [here](https://ahmet.im/blog/cloud-run-multiple-processes-easy-way/) a post from Ahmet for running several process in the same container.

*Note: Ahmet is one of Cloud Run engineers at Google, you can rely on his articles!*

Answer (score 6):

You can now run sidecars in Cloud Run - https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#sidecars

This implies you can run up to 10 containers of your choice in a single cloud run instance in the same network namespace. To find out more details and the use cases around this feature please refer to this - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments

Comment: Cloud Run has started supporting sidecars 2 weeks ago, and I can attest to it as a PM for this feature. There were no sidecars in Cloud Run 3 years ago. Not sure what comment you are referring to.
To add more context, you can find the use cases covered by the feature here - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments

Comment: The comment I am  referring to is the one by John Hanley, three years ago, 2020-01-31 21:46, quote "The short answer is no. Anything you want to do in your container you must do yourself. The exception is Cloud SQL Proxy which is sidecar'd to your container." Do you have trouble finding it? My reading of your post and that comment is very similar. Maybe you are using "sidecar" with a different meaning. I recommend to [edit] your post in order to avoid the kind of misunderstanding I had. Feel free to add the info from your comment, includign the disclosure of your affiliation.

Comment: Unfortunately Cloud Run **Jobs** still only support a single container

Answer (score 3):

This is now suppored by Google Cloud Run
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-now-supports-multi-container-deployments

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have changed.

The [Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract) states "A Cloud Run instance always has one single ingress container, and optionally one or more sidecar containers."

There are instructions for deploying in [Deploying to Cloud Run > Sidecars](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#sidecars) that amounts to

- Create a file named `service.yaml` with multiple `image` entries
- Add any further YAML [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/how-to#configure)
- Deploy with `gcloud run services replace service.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned, the answer is no. Cloud run and App Engine both provide you a simple way to deploy a containerized application int the cloud and have it run.

To keep this as simple and streamlined as possible, additional features that you see in pod specs are not available (such as init containers or running multiple containers).

For more complex deployments, it is recommended to use GKE